# MFC child dialog

Tags: c++, class, mfc, dialog, docking

I have 2 dockPanels inside of MainFrm .

there are buttons on the second panel.

when button(in this case first btn) gets clicked

new dialog which includes static "out" OK, CANCEL buttons will be displayed.

OUT dialog's settings: `border`: `thin`, `style`: child.

[image]

but when I run it
It shows Like this image

**and the PROBLEM is
the buttons which are should be positioned at the end of that dialog,
but there are getting displayed at the center--> which means, I can not display anything at that area from current btns' POS to the bottom.**

[image]

reference:
`OnBnClickedCtrlBtn1Out this->GetClientRect : width = 1582 height = 858`

code is:

```
BOOL ProjDlg::OnInitDialog()
{
    CDialogEx::OnInitDialog();
    

    CRect rect;
    GetClientRect(&rect);

    
    m_CctrlOutDlg.Create(IDD_CTRL_DLG_OUT, this);   

    m_CctrlOutDlg.SetWindowPos(NULL, 0, rect.top+40, rect.Width(), rect.Height()-40, SW_SHOW | SWP_NOZORDER);
    m_CctrlOutDlg.ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
    


    return TRUE;  

}


void ProjDlg::OnBnClickedCtrlBtn1Out()
{
    CRect rectCtrl;
    this->GetClientRect(&rectCtrl);
    
    m_CctrlOutDlg.ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
    
    m_CctrlOutDlg.MoveWindow(rectCtrl.left, rectCtrl.top + 40, rectCtrl.Width(), rectCtrl.Height()-40);
}
```

Comment: There are two issues: `1` Resizing the dialog does not reposition its child controls. You're going to have to implement that manually, or take advantage of MFC's [dynamic layout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/dynamic-layout) support. `2` The call to `SetWindowPos` passes the wrong flags. Specifically, `SW_SHOW` has a value of 5 that is interpreted as `SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOZORDER`. This tells the API call to ignore the desires size. You probably meant to use `SWP_SHOWWINDOW` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED

1. I editted `SetWindowPos`'s flags as @llspectable said (which I did typo)
2. Simply made IDD_DIALOG itself bigger by dragging(??)

[image]

Comment: This merely replaces one problem with another one: Now the dialog is (potentially) too large. The real solution is resize and reposition UI elements at run time, since the information is only available at run time. This is a two-step process: `1` When the host window (presumably `ProjDlg`) is resized, it needs to resize the child dialog. `2` As the child dialog gets resized it needs to reposition its child controls. Either one should be implemented in the respective window's `OnSize` implementation.

Comment: Hey~ Thank you for your quick reply!) I will try to do as you said. But now I have another question if you don't mind. I have a ```pMainFrame``` with 1900 x 1000 size. and also View, which gets displayed fully, and when I check size of View (```void CProjView::OnInitialUpdate()
{ CView::OnInitialUpdate();
 CRect rectWnd_View;
 this->GetClientRect(&rectWnd_View); )``` it's giving me  ```1572 x 531``` size which is quite different from pMainFrame size. My question is why this is giving me small size?? I think at least Width of ```View``` should be same as ```pMainWnd```'s width?

Comment: `GetClientRect` returns the *client area* that's usually smaller than the window area. This is detailed under [Application Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/about-windows#application-windows).

Answer (score 1):

In VS2019 and newer you don't have to write any line of code. The rc Editor has the dynamic layout function capabilities.

For the controls you want to move or sizing set this behaviour in the rc like below

[image]